# How do I display just one value in the x-axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a dataset that contains the following values

```
       order_dates  Sales in Dollars
1          50           10
2          50           15
3          50           20
4          50           30
5          50           35
5          50           45
```

When using ggplot2 and geom_point, I want the x-axis to contain just 1 value -- 50. Right now, ggplot2 includes values before 50 as well. Any ideas I can implement to get the desired result?

Comment: `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 50, labels=50)`

Comment: Or convert `order_dates` to a character instead of numeric

Comment: or use aes(x = "50")  Your aesthetic is thus a constant

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860952/show-a-specific-value-of-x-axis-on-ggplot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096538/customize-axis-labels?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of ways to do that. Here suggestions from the comments, as a community wiki.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- structure(list(order_dates = c(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50), Sales = c(10, 
                                                                        15, 20, 30, 35, 45)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                "tbl", "data.frame"))
## define the breaks
## no need for "label" argument
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = order_dates, Sales)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 50)
```

[image]

```r
## set constant aes (recommended only in very specific cases) as a character
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = "50", Sales))
```

[image]

```r
## convert the variable to character
df$order_dates <- as.character(df$order_dates)
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = order_dates, Sales))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>