# ggplot2 - Display specific values on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to display specific values on x-axis while plotting a line plot on with ggplot2. In my table, I have the num values which are quite distant from each other, that's why I want to plot them as discrete values.

```
line <- ggplot(lineplot, aes(value,num, colour=attribute))
line + geom_line()
```

Hope I've been clear, I'm a very beginner,
apologies in advance for the question

```
example table:
    num value   attribute
a   0   0.003   main
b   1   0.003   low
c   0   0.003   high
d   0   0.6 main
e   9   0.6 low
f   3   0.6 high
g   2   0.9 main
h   2   0.9 low
I   2   0.9 high
```

x-axis:
what i get:

```
0.003                                       0.6           0.9
```

i want:

```
0.003         0.6         0.9
```

Comment: Remove `lineplot$` from inside `aes()`. I find your question very unclear.

Comment: Look into `?ggplot2::theme` The argument `axis.text.x` might be suitable.

Comment: Not clear, either you want to [subset the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition) before plotting or use custom [x-axis values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096538/customize-axis-labels)

Comment: Indeed is exactly what Chase answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096538/customize-axis-labels but i want to do that with ggplot

Comment: A clearer reproducible example would help others to help you.

Comment: added and example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the x axis to be treated like a discrete factor then you have to add the `group` aesthetic to tell ggplot2 which points to connect with a line.

```
df <- read.table(text = "num value   attribute
0   0.003   main
1   0.003   low
0   0.003   high
0   0.6 main
9   0.6 low
3   0.6 high
2   0.9 main
2   0.9 low
2   0.9 high", header = TRUE)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(value), y = num, group = attribute, color = attribute)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to force x-axis to be as factor and not numeric

```
line <- ggplot(lineplot, aes(factor(value),num, colour=attribute))
line + geom_line()
```

Is that what you want ?

Comment: Correct, but if i do that i lose the line (but not the points with geom_point()). i get the error: "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

Comment: @mightaskalot And when you add the group aesthetic it works. See [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48798651/4975218)

Comment: Yes forgot to put the group aes. Check @Claus answer.