# How can I change axis label in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a histogram in R. At the moment, the numbers 1 - 8 are written on the x-axis (for each number a bar). I would like to change the numbers into the wind direction, e.g. instead of 1, there should stand "west".
I tried:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1" = "North", "2" = "North East", "3" = "East", "4"= "South East", "5"= "South", "6"="South West", "7"="West", "8"="North West"))
```

But is not working.I also tried:

```
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), labels=c("North", "North East", "East", "South East", "South", "South West", "West", "North West"))
```

Here is my script:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

input1 <- "C:\\Users\\wind_direction.csv"

wind_direction <- read.csv(input1, sep=";")
library(ggplot2)

p3 <- ggplot(wind_direction, aes(x=winddirection)) + 
  geom_bar(color="black", fill="grey", width=0.9)+ 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 55), breaks = seq(0,55,10),expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("1" = "North", "2" = "North East", "3" = "East", "4"= "South East", "5"= "South", "6"="South West", "7"="West", "8"="North West"))

print(p3)
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
head(wind_direction)
         day     time winddirection
1 31.07.2018 12:51:57             3
2 31.07.2018 12:55:16             3
3 31.07.2018 12:56:29             3
4 31.07.2018 13:25:05             3
5 31.07.2018 13:36:54             3
6 31.07.2018 13:55:37             3
```

[image: My histogram looks at the moment like this]

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(wind_direction)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(wind_direction, 20))`.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `aes(x=winddirection)` with  `aes(x=as.character(winddirection))` ?

Comment: See if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096538/customize-axis-labels) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did a good job with your code and a fast solution involves just to replace `aes(x=winddirection)` with `aes(x=as.character(winddirection))` or `aes(x=as.factor(winddirection))`.

So, you just need to be sure that `winddirection` is character or factor when you map it into `x`.

Just be sure you have the right labeling. You mention in your question that 1 should be west, but in `scale_x_discrete` you declare that 1 is north.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers. @Valentin: I replaced aes(x=winddirection) with aes(x=as.character(winddirection)) or aes(x=as.factor(winddirection)). But unfortunately, it gives me the error: "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (224): x".

Comment: Hi @Dolphin94. It works for me. Try to give it a clean run (clean your environment and run again). It sounds like maybe you edited something in your data.frame `wind_direction` (?) I can replicate your error if instead of `winddirection` I use `wind_direction` in `aes(x=as.character(winddirection))` - might that be the case?

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is working. I used aes(x=as.character(winddirection)), but the correct form is aes(x=as.character(wind_direction))

Comment: That is confusing because you cannot map your data frame  `wind_direction` into `x`, but your column `winddirection` . Did you swap their names somehow?

Comment: I am sorry for confusing you. Yes, I swapped inadvertently their names in the script. The name of my excel file is wind_direction and the name of the column is winddirection. Therefore, I wrote: aes(x=as.character(winddirection). And now it is working.