# how to change x axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

trying to change the x axis labels but when I run the part of the code that's #'d out, it gets rid of all the values on the axis, rather than replacing them with the labels I indicated.

```
median_income %>% ggplot(aes(y = estimate, x = name, color = sex)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_path(aes(group = name), size = .5, color = "gray65") +
  theme_din(xgrid = T, ygrid = F) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#D9CFE4", "#766A84")) +
  labs(y = "Median income ($)", x = NULL, title = "Median indiviual earnings", subtitle = "Full-time, year-round workers, 2017") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  #scale_y_discrete(labels = c("50k", "100k", "150k", "200k")) +
  coord_flip()
```

instead of no axis, I want the values in labels = c() to become my axis labels.

sample data:

```
name <- c("Darien", "Stratford", "Darien", "Stratford")
sex <- c("male", "male", "female", "female")
estimate <- c(217813, 63105, 87946, 50764)
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate to the following question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096538/customize-axis-labels).

Comment: Please share sample data so we can run your code.

Comment: In other words, change `scale_y_discrete` to `scale_y_continuous`.

Comment: when I change to scale y continuous I get this error: Error in f(..., self = self) : Breaks and labels are different lengths

Comment: Use argument `breaks = seq(50e3, 200e3, by = 50e3)` and then the same `labels`.