# ggplot missing plot with x-axis factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, factors

The following works fine:

```
my_df <- data.frame(x_val = 1:10, y_val = sample(1:20,10), 
            labels = sample(c("a", "b"), 10, replace = T))
ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = x_val, y = y_val)) + geom_line()
```

but if I chance `x_val` to factor, I am getting blank plot and message:

```
my_df <- data.frame(x_val = 1:10, y_val = sample(1:20,10), 
          labels = sample(c("a", "b"), 10, replace = T))
my_df$x_val <- as.factor(my_df$x_val)
ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = x_val, y = y_val)) + geom_line()
```

message:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you
need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

I can obviously drop `factor` conversion, but I need it in order to replace labels of x axis with `scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:10,labels= my_df$labels)`. Here is where I borrowed it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096538/customize-axis-labels)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just leave `x_val` as numeric and use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10,labels= my_df$labels)` instead?

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I also found that adding `group= 1` helps. `aes(x = x_val, y = y_val, group = 1)`