# How can I change the bar names in ggplot geom_bar and the legend title?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data frame  :

```
id = c("A","B","C","D","E")
C1 = c(T,F,T,F,T)
DAT = tibble(id,C1);DAT
ggplot(DAT,aes(C1,color="lightblue"))+ geom_bar(aes(color="black",fill = "red"))
```

I want to create a bar chart like this one :

[image]

But I want to change the true to "ok" and false to "not ok" and also this renaming to appear in the legend at the right with title not colour but "Check". How can I do it in R?

**Optional**

If I had a row with NA how I could change that ?
For example:

```
id = c("A","B","C","D","E")
C1 = c(T,F,NA,F,T)
DAT = tibble(id,C1);DAT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

id <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
C1 <- c(T, F, T, F, T, NA)
DAT <- tibble(id, C1)
DAT
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   id    C1   
#>   <chr> <lgl>
#> 1 A     TRUE 
#> 2 B     FALSE
#> 3 C     TRUE 
#> 4 D     FALSE
#> 5 E     TRUE 
#> 6 F     NA

DAT |>
  mutate(C1 = case_when(
    C1 == TRUE ~ "ok",
    C1 == FALSE ~ "not ok",
    TRUE ~ "not declared"
  )) |>
  ggplot(aes(C1, fill = C1)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(fill = "Check")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: and if i had a row with NA ?

Comment: If you don't want to see the NAs, you could `drop_na() |>` before the `mutate`. That would exclude the row if either or both columns are NA. `drop_na(id)` if you only wanted to exclude for the one column.

Comment: no i want to keep them but to rename the bar name NA that will appear to "not declared"

Comment: Then you can do the above. `case_when` is useful if you have more than two conditions. `TRUE` covers everything else not covered by the first two conditions.

Comment: I tried `DAT %>%
  mutate(C1 = case_when(
    C1 == TRUE ~ "ok",
    C1 == FALSE ~ "not ok",
    NA ~ "not declared"
  ))%>% 
  ggplot(aes(C1, fill = C1)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(fill = "Check")` but the NA as a bar name remains.

Comment: `is.na(NA) ~ "not declared"`

Comment: awesome.thank you for your clear answers.i appreciate it.you are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

In place of `if_else` you can use `case_when` which allows to vectorise multiple `if_else()` statements like

```
library(tidyverse)

id = c("A","B","C","D","E")
C1 = c(T,F,T,F,T)
DAT = tibble(id,C1)

DAT  %>% 
  mutate(C2 = case_when(C1 == TRUE ~ "OK",
            C1 == FALSE ~ "Not OK")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(C2, fill = C2)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  labs(fill = "Check")
```

[image]

Comment: and if i had a row with NA ?

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096538/customize-axis-labels):

```
library(tidyverse)
id = c("A","B","C","D","E")
C1 = c(T,F,T,F,T)
DAT = tibble(id,C1)

ggplot(
  DAT,
  aes(C1,color="lightblue")) + 
  geom_bar(aes(color="black", fill = "red")) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks = c(FALSE, TRUE),
    labels = c("not ok", "ok"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To have variables appear in your legends, avoid fixing the colour, e.g. `fill = "lightblue"`, instead use the variable you want, e.g. `fill = C1`

```
id = c("A","B","C","D","E")
C1 = c(T,F,T,F,T)
DAT = tibble(id,C1);DAT
    
ggplot(DAT,aes(C1)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = C1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Not OK", "OK")) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Not Ok", "OK"), values = c("darkred", "darkblue")) +
  labs(fill = "Anything here")
```

[image]