# How do I change labels in a graph?

Tags: r, graph, label

I have created a graph that shows the estimated regression coefficients and 95% confidence intervals for each school for four variables.

Here is the code for it:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
sem_params <- tidy(scalar, conf.int = TRUE)
sem_regression_coefs <- sem_params %>%
  filter(op == "~") %>%
  separate(term, into = c("outcome", "predictor"), sep = " ~ ") %>%
  mutate(group = factor(group, levels = 1:2,
                        labels = c("Democratic schools", "Mainstream schools")))
ggplot(sem_regression_coefs,
       aes(x = estimate, xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high,
           y = predictor, colour = group)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey50") +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1.5, 1.5),
                     breaks = seq(-1.5, 1.5, by = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) +
  facet_wrap(vars(outcome)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())
ggsave("/Users/NehaS/Desktop/sem_regression_coef_plot.png", width = 7, height = 3.5, dpi = 300)
```

It works and creates this graph:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a3V4.png)

However, I need to change the variable labels as follows:

1. MeaningLife to ML
2. MeaningWork1 to MW-PPM
3. MeaningWork2 to MW-GGM
4. selfEff to GSE
5. academics to AC
6. family to FR
7. FX to PF

How do I go about doing this?

I tried changing variable names, but it will not accept names with - i.e., MW-PPM and MW-GGM. I need these names because that is how I have referred to the variables in my thesis.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please kinldy provide some sample data to make the question reproducible. You can use `dput()` for this

Comment: You can use whatever names you like in R as long as you wrap them in backticks. For example ```list(`MW-PPM` = "MeaningWork1")``` is perfectly legal R syntax.

Comment: You are simply asking how to change both the facet and axes labels - this is a frequent question with multiple answers - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34811062/12109788) for facet labels and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096538/customize-axis-labels) for axes labels, to start